# when using ejabberd 19.05 with MySQL I always see empty sql tables, except ejabberd.sm

Tags: mysql, ejabberd

I'm trying to enforce ejabberd to not use Mnesia db but use Mysql.

I have followed all the docs about how to configure this. And looks like it's working.

This is my ejabberd.yml configuration file. As you can see I even tried with old/new db schema:

```
###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###

language: "en"

default_db: sql
#new_sql_schema: true
sm_db_type: sql

###   ====================
###   ODBC DATABASE CONFIG
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_port: 3306
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "ejabberd"
sql_password: "password"

hosts:
  - "localhost"

certfiles:
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"

ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

loglevel: 5
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

auth_method: external
extauth_program: "auth.py --config /etc/auth.ini"
auth_use_cache: false


listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    access: c2s
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5225
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_service
    access: all
    check_from: false
    shaper: fast
    hosts:
      "jaxlecho.localhost":
        password: "pass"
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "0.0.0.0"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
        "/http-bind": mod_bosh

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
      - "::1/128"
      - "::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128"

access_rules:
  local:
    - allow: local
  c2s:
    - deny: blocked
    - allow
  trusted_network:
    - allow

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
      - oauth:
        - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        - access:
          - allow:
            - acl: loopback
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "status"
      - "connected_users_number"

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  c2s_shaper:
    - none: admin
    - fast
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@debian9.localdomain"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_cobrowser: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_ping:
    send_pings: true
    ping_interval: 15
    ping_ack_timeout: 32
    timeout_action: none
  mod_privacy: {}
```

When I start ejabberd, this is what I can see in the logs:

```
2019-09-05 14:44:18.724 [notice] <0.123.0>@lager_file_backend:152 Changed loghwm of /opt/ejabberd/logs/error.log to 100
2019-09-05 14:44:18.724 [notice] <0.123.0>@lager_file_backend:152 Changed loghwm of /opt/ejabberd/logs/ejabberd.log to 100
2019-09-05 14:44:18.849 [info] <0.106.0>@ejabberd_config:start:70 Loading configuration from /opt/ejabberd/conf/ejabberd.yml
2019-09-05 14:44:19.611 [notice] <0.123.0>@lager_file_backend:141 Changed loglevel of /opt/ejabberd/logs/ejabberd.log to debug
2019-09-05 14:44:19.736 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:init:72 Waiting for Mnesia tables synchronization...
2019-09-05 14:44:19.777 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:read_schema_file:227 No custom Mnesia schema file found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.808 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'ejabberd_commands' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.816 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 's2s' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.816 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'temporarily_blocked' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.817 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'acl' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.817 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'access' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.820 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'shaper' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.825 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'sql_pool' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.456.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "w!;E*??_Clw4:fq)q%\\$" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.452.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "H<1#Ywl:xrPx0~OO~OMu" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.459.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "LF[tY?n0>*WV,u+s'b<C" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.451.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "wF4sf',G_)K~\\0z9HAJ4" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.460.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "mERJ[k*-CI'%$$(<6;b^" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.453.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "Nh?@dVbjlb'6|0t|1|@h" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.463.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "Jk^sJVQrkABga3w\">Rbs" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.465.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "OjJpw'V]P[W\"@]4+zF/X" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.454.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "/t}78Sx%J&}gmkQ5R|<U" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.466.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "vSz0z<X'UZD&.S;l/DI!" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.455.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "!zhxF0^gnod);/u&Ym8p" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.469.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "k>3#S\\TnMv+mhBNA:?k!" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.457.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "fp\"RV;deO<{wg|\\66L^p" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.470.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "!zhyJE[wfwE1e*@Cm~PT" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.461.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "^4*q|@dWh&~m)#o+'!k|" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "Emy9KN's4E?K<)X_Tg,B" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.464.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "tQu|0w)a1mR5Ppe+CPJa" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.855 [debug] <0.468.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "4YD(9(\\uX9T{1|@fc@Uk" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.859 [debug] <0.462.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "_m)|[1#Zzxm9rV5GFi_\"" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_conn: greeting version "5.5.5-10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1" (protocol 10) salt "Es6NiE[ztX=goy2,$lw4" caps 2688546815 serverchar 45 auth_plug: "mysql_native_password"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.456.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,171,53,210,169,212,231,142,1,57,220,193,8,197,151,251,188,70,0,223,38,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.462.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,107,186,157,190,74,38,250,80,46,141,3,100,228,9,36,109,4,249,123,193,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.451.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,1,148,40,101,46,165,16,16,77,128,225,70,199,114,205,219,144,90,243,180,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.453.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,224,232,129,199,219,253,14,226,216,86,26,183,240,31,216,176,122,4,21,107,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.452.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,100,174,122,193,97,72,78,143,38,179,150,148,60,112,251,18,49,192,217,103,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.454.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,173,67,127,140,203,49,157,123,85,6,97,123,213,22,243,49,232,96,206,96,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.455.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,41,90,195,84,140,57,220,176,51,232,237,90,50,203,88,249,45,177,10,77,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.459.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,214,6,180,81,45,178,254,203,123,240,88,147,227,121,141,61,234,96,178,216,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.457.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,143,32,122,15,96,36,237,0,59,138,132,7,98,109,17,198,12,122,144,30,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.860 [debug] <0.460.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,217,25,190,99,180,133,75,225,234,169,54,235,212,73,186,21,138,9,191,224,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.458.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,206,132,227,228,90,61,233,142,159,41,108,202,18,128,219,120,70,99,151,180,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.468.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,134,52,30,224,115,143,248,249,24,228,93,124,56,236,165,123,239,71,157,230,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.463.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,211,202,124,120,130,207,114,21,49,192,227,182,76,157,177,233,112,144,200,87,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.465.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,223,226,28,107,37,108,110,159,31,213,103,218,35,205,162,53,184,120,244,88,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.466.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,75,148,231,246,70,171,24,158,211,30,245,151,169,81,218,56,82,236,17,145,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.469.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,100,225,238,172,132,188,46,242,126,10,137,210,84,0,13,206,201,238,132,144,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.470.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,117,194,92,10,219,73,102,34,110,67,106,21,240,150,29,226,110,43,1,230,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.461.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,224,125,29,165,224,63,237,60,15,213,146,252,122,57,175,193,191,6,40,157,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.861 [debug] <0.464.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,208,154,125,246,250,53,190,159,139,219,195,217,71,52,167,65,106,134,44,214,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.862 [debug] <0.467.0>@ejabberd_sql:log:991 p1_mysql_auth send packet 1: <<7,162,8,0,64,66,15,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,101,106,97,98,98,101,114,100,0,20,236,52,244,227,35,5,222,166,120,38,247,79,215,192,88,85,221,128,123,69,109,121,115,113,108,95,110,97,116,105,118,101,95,112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,0>>
2019-09-05 14:44:19.890 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'route' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.890 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'route_multicast' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.891 [debug] <0.508.0>@ejabberd_router:register_route:179 Route registered: localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.891 [debug] <0.508.0>@ejabberd_router:register_route:179 Route registered: vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.896 [debug] <0.510.0>@ejabberd_sm_sql:init:49 Cleaning SQL SM table...
2019-09-05 14:44:19.899 [debug] <0.427.0>@ejabberd_sql:sql_query_internal:639 SQL: "delete from sm where node='ejabberd@localhost'"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.902 [debug] <0.439.0>@ejabberd_sql:sql_query_internal:639 SQL: "delete from sm where node='ejabberd@localhost'"
2019-09-05 14:44:19.903 [debug] <0.514.0>@ejabberd_captcha:get_prog_name:421 The option captcha_cmd is not configured, but some module wants to use the CAPTCHA feature.
2019-09-05 14:44:19.912 [info] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_modules:131 Loading modules for localhost and vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.917 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_ping at localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.917 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_privacy at localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.929 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_blocking at localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.929 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_bosh at localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.929 [debug] <0.221.0>@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'bosh' found
2019-09-05 14:44:19.930 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_cobrowser at localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.930 [info] <0.362.0>@mod_cobrowser:start:25 Loading mod_cobrowser: hooks attached successfully
2019-09-05 14:44:19.930 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_carboncopy at localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:19.935 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_ping at vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.935 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_privacy at vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.936 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_blocking at vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.936 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_bosh at vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.936 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_cobrowser at vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:19.936 [info] <0.362.0>@mod_cobrowser:start:25 Loading mod_cobrowser: hooks attached successfully
2019-09-05 14:44:19.936 [debug] <0.362.0>@gen_mod:start_module:207 Loading mod_carboncopy at vagrant.cobrowser.io
2019-09-05 14:44:20.015 [info] <0.106.0>@ejabberd_cluster_mnesia:wait_for_sync:123 Waiting for Mnesia synchronization to complete
2019-09-05 14:44:20.095 [warning] <0.386.0>@ejabberd_pkix:log_warnings:397 Invalid certificate in /opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem: at line 53: self-signed certificate
2019-09-05 14:44:20.097 [info] <0.106.0>@ejabberd_app:start:60 ejabberd 19.05 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost in 1.57s
2019-09-05 14:44:20.101 [info] <0.385.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:140 Start accepting TCP connections at 0.0.0.0:5280 for ejabberd_http
2019-09-05 14:44:20.102 [info] <0.384.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:140 Start accepting TCP connections at 0.0.0.0:5225 for ejabberd_service
2019-09-05 14:44:20.102 [info] <0.383.0>@ejabberd_listener:init:140 Start accepting TCP connections at 0.0.0.0:5222 for ejabberd_c2s

2019-09-05 14:44:23.285 [info] <0.384.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:245 (<0.553.0>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:37386 -> 127.0.0.1:5225
2019-09-05 14:44:23.297 [info] <0.553.0> (tcp|<0.553.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<stream:stream xmlns:stream=\"http://etherx.jabber.org/streams\" xmlns=\"jabber:component:accept\" to=\"jaxlecho.localhost\">">>
2019-09-05 14:44:23.313 [info] <0.553.0> (tcp|<0.553.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='7150557642597348197' xml:lang='en' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' from='jaxlecho.localhost' xmlns='jabber:component:accept'>">>
2019-09-05 14:44:23.314 [info] <0.553.0> (tcp|<0.553.0>) Received XML on stream = <<"<handshake>d74479b7110a80b3dcfd8960efbf83b1db5e5cc6</handshake>">>
2019-09-05 14:44:23.326 [info] <0.553.0>@ejabberd_service:handle_auth_success:161 (tcp|<0.553.0>) Accepted external component handshake authentication for jaxlecho.localhost from 127.0.0.1
2019-09-05 14:44:23.326 [debug] <0.553.0>@ejabberd_router:register_route:179 Route registered: jaxlecho.localhost
2019-09-05 14:44:23.326 [info] <0.553.0> (tcp|<0.553.0>) Send XML on stream = <<"<handshake/>">>
```

As you can see in the logs, ejabberd is able to communicate with MySQL properly. However there're several logs about mnesia schemas not found, like:

```
@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'bosh' found
```

I've checked all the tables inside MySQL and all of them except `ejabberd.sm` table are always empty.

Most important for our case is `bosh`, we're using it and we can see `Session ID Mismatch` in the logs when we start several ejabberd instances.

My questions are: 
  - even configuring ejabberd 19.05 to use MySQL, is it still using mnesia under the hoods ? We'd like to use only MySQL DB and share it across multiple ejabberd instances.
  - any clue about why we still see `@ejabberd_mnesia:schema:204 No custom Mnesia schema for table 'bosh' found` in the logs ? Perhaps related with my previous question.
  - why all tables are empty except `ejabberd.sm`, but specially `ejabberd.bosh` table ? we're using bosh so I guess we should see there `sid, node, pid` values, right? or am I wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let's see `SHOW TABLE STATUS;`

Comment: In your config file you have only 6 modules enabled. Which tables did you expect to get filled? From those modules, the only one that uses DB is mod_privacy, which is only used if the client specifically request it. Maybe nothing is stored in mnesia either: check the mnesia stats in WebAdmin -> Nodes -> your node -> database; or see the mnesia content by storing a plain text backup of mnesia.